# Making a YouTube Channel Private

Tags: youtube

I am trying to make a private youtube channel.

When I follow instructions I've found like from tutorials like [this](https://castos.com/make-a-youtube-channel-private/), the channel dissapears completely.

When I search the YouTube help center directly I don't even see a hit for how to make a channel private, just how to "hide" the channel.

Is it possible to create a private channel and then invite specific users to that channel as described in this tutorial:
https://castos.com/make-a-youtube-channel-private/

I do not want to just make videos private, I'd like to the whole channel private as it's a concept in development and is not ready to be public.